# Calculating a rectangular Wilson loop for the free photon

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, regularization, wilson-loop

I'm studying Creutz's Quarks, gluons and lattices, in chapter 6 on page 33, we have the following exercise

> Calculate a rectangular Wilson loop for the field theory of free photons. Using any convenient regulator, show how the leading divergence scales with the loop perimeter. Show that the ratio of two such loops with the same perimeter and number of corners is finite as the cutoff is removed.

My understanding is that for the free photon, the four potential is given by $$A^\mu(x)=A^\mu e^{ik\cdot x}$$ where $k$ is a time like vector and $A^\mu$ is a polarization vector.

Is my understanding correct? Also why do we need any regulator here? The Wilson loop is simply given by $$U(S)=\exp\bigg(ig_0\int_0^s ds\frac{dx_\mu}{ds}A^\mu\bigg)$$ which is a finite number. What does it mean to regularize the Wilson loop?

Comment: Maybe Creutz means "Vacuum expectation of the Wilson loop" when simply saying "Wilson loop"?

Comment: I guess he could mean the vacuum expectation of the Wilson loop, but is there actually an exact formula for the vacuum expectation of the Wilson loop? And what does he mean by regularize? Does he mean lattice regularize, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, there is an exact formula. For what is meant by "regularize", you can check Srednicki's book on the subject: https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf , its page 496.